# How to write an Excel formula that can perform calculations based on certain key values with a variable amount of rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to learn more about how you can write formulas for multidimensional variable length excel tables. For example, if I wanted to find if PALLET is divisible by LAYER for all brands of shoes, how could I write a formula that accomplishes this within one cell?

An expected result would look like this:

| Shoe Brand | Measure | Amount | Is PALLET divisible by LAYER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike Shoes | BOX | 1 | Yes |
| Nike Shoes | LAYER | 5 | Yes |
| Nike Shoes | PALLET | 25 | Yes |
| Adidas Shoes | BOX | 1 | No |
| Adidas Shoes | LAYER | 4 | No |
| Adidas Shoes | LAYER2 | 5 | No |
| Adidas Shoes | PALLET | 10 | No |
| Sketchers Shoes | LAYER | 3 | Yes |
| Sketchers Shoes | PALLET | 6 | Yes |

I recently learned about using =COUNTIFS to compare criteria 'two dimensionally' for a variable amount of lines. If I try something like `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"LAYER")>0, "Yes", "No")` I can check if every brand of shoe has a 'LAYER'. There is an added level of complexity to this though as the 'criteria' involves checking separate rows and performing a calculation on them.

Comment: So why "No" for `Adidas Shoes` `LAYER2`?

Comment: Because the formula is only checking if PALLET is divisible by 'LAYER' for that brand. In this case it would do 10 divided by 4, which does not work, therefore all Adidas Shoes should have 'NO'.

Comment: Ok, so other layers are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using an Excel Table:

```
=IF(MOD(
    PRODUCT(
        XLOOKUP([@[Shoe Brand]]&"|"&{"PALLET","LAYER"},
        [Shoe Brand]&"|"&[Measure],[Amount])^
        {1,-1}),1
    ),
    "No",
    "Yes"
)
```